# Dynamic Array of Integers In CLI

Tags: arrays, dynamic, int, command-line-interface

I'm relatively new to CLI and I need to keep an array of int values and it needs to be expandable (dynamic).  ArrayList doesn't like int because it's not an "object".

What is the ArrayList equivalent for holding ints or doubles?

EDIT: Oh lord.  I'm way off my game today.  It doesn't have a problem with int.  I just have to typecast it to int when I index the array.  Sorry for wasting your time...

Comment: Can you use the Integer class?

Comment: No Integer class in CLI it seems.  I tried using UInt32 and it works.  So, thanks for pointing me in the right direction!  Post an actual answer so I can give you a bump.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question seems to be too open ended. The best I can answer is you can either use a generic list (`System.Collections.Generic.List`) or box the integers, in which case they'll act as objects. Are you writing IL? A compiler?

Comment: ArrayList is the expandable array class I tried to use.  if I try to add an int to an ArrayList, I get a compiler error.  The suggestion to use Int32 instead of int worked.  Is that not a good way to do it?  Is there a lot of overhead?  This is not for a compiler but speed is key to it being useful.  However, this is a prototype so I will probably port it to straight C++ for speed (and wrap it in CLI) when it's working, so speed is not my main concern right now. Is what you're saying different?

Comment: int and Int32 are literally identical. The c# compiler just uses int as an alias. If you look at the assembly, they'll be the same. Just so you know going forward ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<int>
```

there is no such thing as an "expandable array" in C++.

Comment: @Dedic: Typo regarding C#, but same answer -- you need to use `List<T>`.

Comment: You don't _need_ to, but this will be more performant and make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

As I was asked, use one of the "class" forms of int, such as UInt32 or Int32. I'm pretty sure John's answer is better than this though and from memory, works correctly.

Comment: int is just an alias for Int32. There is no "class" form of an integer in .Net as there is in Java. Instead, value types (stack allocated) are moved to the heap by a process called "boxing." For example, if you type `object o = 3;`, the value 3 will be automagically boxed and placed on the heap. Later on, if you cast it to an int (`(int) o`), it will be unboxed.